# Django CreateView - Display only particular objects in foreignkey field

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I have a `CreateView` view that holds a bunch of fields that need to be filled by the user when creating a new contact. Now, I want the user to be able to see and choose only from the categories that they'd created.
This is the model of Category:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('category')
        verbose_name_plural = _('categories')

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

This is the view:

```
class ContactCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.edit.CreateView):
    model = models.Contact
    success_url = reverse_lazy('site:contacts')
    fields = ['firstname', 'lastname', 'phone1', 'phone2', 'email', 'city', 'category']
    template_name = 'site/contacts.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_contacts'
```

What I need the user to see is a select that has only the categories which include the appropriate profile foreign key associated with them.

I'd be glad to get some help with this. Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can override the `get_form` method of the view and set the queryset of the appropriate field:

```
class ContactCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.edit.CreateView):
    # ...
    def get_form(self, *args, **kwargs):
        form = super(ContactCreate, self).get_form(*args, **kwargs)
        form.fields['categories'].queryset = Category.objects.filter(profile=self.request.user.profile)
        return form
```

This, of course, assumes that your `Profile` model has a `OneToOneField` to `User` with `related_name` `'profile'`, otherwise you'd have to adjust the filtering.